# Closed as duplicate: What should you say if a latecomer is silent about the lateness, and doesn't even apologise?

Tags: discussion

[What should you say if a latecomer is silent about the lateness, and doesn't even apologise?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6392/2423) was closed as being duplicating [How to reply genuinely (but politely) to apologies for lateness?](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/questions/6287/how-to-reply-genuinely-but-politely-to-apologies-for-lateness?noredirect=1&lq=1).

But the distinction should be evident: the former asks about latecomers who say nothing about their lateness, whereas the latter latecomers who do apologize. Introducing a complaint against someone, appears to me likely more antagonising and offensive than replying to someone's apology?

Comment: You should update your goal on that question. I would close that as unclear, because you don't state your goal there.

Comment: And question can be closed as duplicate although it has differences, if the answer in the referred question can solve your problem.

Comment: I don't understand how these two questions are duplicates.

Comment: @Vylix that really puts a damper on yes/no questions...  ;D

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I've removed the duplicate. These are clearly questions that are two sides of the same idea but they are clearly different questions.

In the future, when asking very similar questions, it's recommended that you include a reference to the other question that actually emphasizes how the two are different. You did refer to the other post but didn't explain what separates the two.

> This question is distinguished from [this](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6287/2423), and concerns only latecomers in professional contexts (e.g. a physician, lawyer, business or government employee).

But saying "is distinguished from" doesn't do enough. I recommend something more like:

> This is related to but different from my [similar question here](https://interpersonal.stackexchange.com/q/6287/2423) in that this refers to people who **fail** to acknowledge their tardiness while the other is about responding to people who **do** apologize.

This makes it obvious to casual observers that the questions are different and how. If users don't see the difference you suggest exists, they may still vote it a duplicate but this should help in cases like these where the questions really are different.